# Lua - Creating a lookup table that handles a nil value?

Tags: lua

I have one Lua table that I want to use as a look up for another table, and while I can get it to work when there is a matching ID/key, I can’t make handle blanks (entries with no key to map.)

To explain what I mean, I create the follow room number/ID to room name table this way..

```
local room_index = {}
for i,n in pairs (luup.rooms) do
    room_index[i] = n
end
```

Which creates the following..

```
{ [1]="Kitchen", [2]="Outside", [3]="Living Room", [4]="Front Room", [5]="Office", [6]="Hallway", [7]="Conservatory", [8]="Landing", [9]="Emma's Room", [10]="Lean To", [11]="Back Landing", [12]="Front Landing", [13]="Boiler Room", [14]="Loft Landing", [15]="Ben's Room", [16]="Main Bedroom", [17]="Under Stairs" }
```

I then I look to the a devices table to show which device is in which room.

```
for i,d in pairs(luup.devices) do
    local r = d.room_num
 print(room_index[r], d.description)
end
```

Which creates the following ..

```
Office     ZRC-90U Controller     
Kitchen     TKB Energy     
nil     Home Energy Meter Gen5     
nil     Clamp 1     
Living Room     Living Room Media     
nil     WWN Home/Away - Home     
Under Stairs     Under Stairs Temp     
Under Stairs     Under Stairs Power     
Living Room     TV Headphones
```

The problem I have is that I can’t work out how to handle the nil values, where there is not an Room number/ID associated with the device, how do I handle this? Rather than nil, I’d just like it to say "No Room"

I looked at various other SO posts, which seem quite complex. Surely this is something relatively straight forward when doing look up tables ? It’s like I need a default  [nil]="No Room" entry somewhere?

Comment: Maybe instead of nil, you could make it 0 or -1 for "No Room"?

Comment: Sadly, it’s a proprietary table, so I unfortunately can’t alter how it’s populated

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your table to return `"No Room"` when indexed with `nil`, you can implement that using a metatable:

```lua
setmetatable(room_index, {__index = function(self, key)
    if key == nil then return "No Room" end
end})
```

Be warned that this may increase the error-proneness of your application: Something like `room_index[uninitialized_variable]` will return `"No Room"` as well.

Comment: Hi @LMD, looking my two blocks of code above , where would this ‘metatable’ go ?

Comment: @nodecentral right below `local room_index = {}`

Comment: Hi @LMD, I placed your metatable where you suggested, leaving everything else as is, and the final print statement still returns `Nil` ? Did I need to remove anything ?

Comment: @nodecentral could it be that the `key` isn't actually `nil` but rather a valid key (a number, string, boolean or a reference type) that just isn't present in your room index? You could just simplify the `__index` function to `return "No Room"` if you wanted that as a default.

Comment: That’s’ it !! In the luup.devices table,  if a Room is not assigned to a device, it’s actually given a 0 (zero) value; and because that was not in the room_index table that’s why I was getting the nil returns

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to index a table with `nil` (see the other answer), I don't think it's the best solution to the issue, or a clean solution at all. Lua uses `nil` in a few special places when iterating through a table, and using it for something meaningful is counterintuitive.

If all you want is to be able to turn `nil` into a custom text, you don't have to use a metatable for that; use a function:

```lua
function room_name(index)
  if index then
    return room_index[index]
  end
  return "No Room"
end
```

Or, if it could make sense to represent a "No Room" entity as an actual entity, for other purposes, just use a non-`nil` value:

```lua
local no_room = -1

room_index[no_room] = "No Room"

for i,d in pairs(luup.devices) do
  local r = d.room_num
  print(room_index[r or no_room], d.description)
end
```

Or, if you cannot assume that -1 be an invalid index, use a string or `{}` to index it; it's all the same to Lua.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in it's current form, your function handles `false` the same as `nil`. Another alternative for a "no room" entity is using the boolean `false` as a key.

Comment: Hi @IS4, looking at my two blocks of code, where exactly would I put that `room_name(index)` function ?

Comment: @nodecentral you'd use it to replace the indexing operation `room_index[something]`.

Answer (score -1):

In this particular situation the table I was doing the look ups from, stored devices with no room associated with a 0 (zero),  so in the end I could use that.

```
local room_index = {}
for i,n in pairs (luup.rooms) do
    room_index[i] = n
end

print (pretty(room_index))

for i,d in pairs(luup.devices) do
    local r = d.room_num
    if r ~= 0 then print(room_index[r], d.description)
        else print ("No Room", d.description)
    end
end
```

Comment: Well then this is not really much of an answer if it circumvents the assumption of the question. Also you can just use `room_index[0] = "No Room"` not make the code less complicated.

Comment: Great point, but In this situation, considering the proprietary sources used, I could only relate my answer to what i saw.. I’m still interested and greatly appreciative of all the related answers ;-)